# Error: optional file(_GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT) Porting error 32bit to 64 bit

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-22.04

When I compiled the code in ubuntu 14.04 of 32 bit , I didn't get any error, but when I ported the code and tried to compile in Ubuntu 22.04 64bit.So I am getting error in standard header libraries. below is the error:

```
usr/include/c++/11/optional: In function ‘void std::__throw_bad_optional_access()’:
/usr/include/c++/11/optional:122:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  122 |   { _GLIBCXX_THROW_OR_ABORT(bad_optional_access()); }
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Not sure if this is related to boost library issue or porting issues, not sure where to do the changes.

Comment: What code? Please show a [mre] and the full compiler output

Comment: This looks like a broken C++ compiler installation.

Comment: or your build scripts hand-set strange version-specific defines for your old Ubuntu 14.04 compiler

Comment: optional file is part of standard library which is inside /usr/includec++/11/ path.